# Measuring total relative influence of groups in particular coefficients in a multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

Suppose I have run a multiple regression model:
*Y = B<sub>0</sub> + x<sub>1</sub>B<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>2</sub>B<sub>2</sub> +..+ x<sub>n</sub>B<sub>n</sub>*, weighted by *w*, from a dataset with such covariates and the weight variable of size *N*. Say there is another column in the data, categorical (a, b or c) and not fitted as a covariate but such that the *N* observations can be distinguished into 3 subsets.

How would I go about measuring the influence on a particular coefficient, *B<sub>i</sub>*, from all the observations that belong in group a, b or c such that I can have *n + 1* sets of (including the intercept) of 3 scalable values or percentages that represent the group's impact on each coefficient? In my case, I have square terms (x<sub>i</sub><sup>2</sup>B<sub>i+j</sub>), interactions and dummy variables in the regression.

I'm thinking it has something to do with cook's distance, but I can only seem to find sources that measure the impact on the model as a whole and only for single observations.